# Pass anchor id and button id to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which works just fine for one block and saves the div element as image. I am using html5 canvas. How I can achieve to pass the id and other variables to jquery if I have n numbers of such div with unique ids.

Here is my code below:-

```
<body>
<div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div>

<div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div><div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div>


<div class="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var getCanvas; // global variable
 $(".btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
    element=$('.html-content-holder');
//  getCanvas;
    preview= element.find(".previewImage");
     html2canvas(element, {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $(".previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $(".btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $(".btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
});

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: use class attribute

Comment: You can use class instead of ID attribute.

Comment: oh now i see your updated code. I will update  my solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Markup:**
You have to add a parent div for each repeated group and change ID to class, and use `find` to query.

```
    <div class="block-holder">
    <div class="html-content-holder" style="">
      <strong>Codepedia.info</strong>
      <hr/>
      <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>

    </div>
    <input class="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview" />
    <a class="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div class="previewImage">
    </div> 
  </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function() {
    parent = $(this).closest('.block-holder');
    element=parent.find('.html-content-holder')
    //  getCanvas;
    console.log(parent,element);
    preview = element.find(".previewImage");
    html2canvas(element, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        $(".previewImage").html(canvas);

      }
    });
  });

  $(".btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function() {
   parent = $(this).closest('.block-holder');
   getCanvas = parent.find('canvas')[0];
   console.log(parent,getCanvas)
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $(".btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
  });

});
```

You can see `preview= element.find(".previewImage")`, use same technique to for `getcanvas` variable and else.

Here is running fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5cfz2ufp/10/

Comment: i tried your code it is not working. please suggest some awesome javascript book. javascript is creating problem for me. here is fiddle.    https://jsfiddle.net/5cfz2ufp/1/

Comment: I learned JS by some online video tutorial. But, for quick, try googling about `debugger` and `console.log`, it's my life-vest.